# Generation of closure systems

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

A closure system on $\Omega$ is any collection of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Omega$ such that:

1. $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$;
2. $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections.

Given a collection of subsets $\mathcal{G}$, it is always possible to construct the smallest closure system $\mathcal{G}^*$ containing $\mathcal{G}$ as the intersection of all the closure systems containing $\mathcal{G}$. However, my question is: if $\Omega$ is infinite, is it possible to construct its smallest closure system recursively, so that any element of $\mathcal{G}^*$ could be obtained (through intersections in this case) from a finite number of elements of $\mathcal{G} \cup \{\Omega\}$?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible, since not every element in $\mathcal F$ has to be a finite intersection of elements from $\mathcal G\cup\{\Omega\}$. Take for example the set $\mathcal G$ of all sets of the form $X_n=\Omega\setminus\{n\}$ for some $n\in\Omega$. Then any intersection of finitely many elements of $\mathcal G$ is cofinite: $X_{n_1}\cap \cdots\cap X_{n_k}=\Omega\setminus\{n_1,\dots,n_k\}$ is an infinite set.

Meanwhile, $\bigcap \mathcal G\in\mathcal F$ is quite clearly the empty set, since $\bigcap\mathcal G\subset X_n$ for any $n\in\Omega$, and thus $n\notin \bigcap\mathcal G$ for any $n\in\Omega$.

---

There's no need for recursion to construct $\mathcal F$, since the closure system $\mathcal F$ is directly definable from $\mathcal G$ and $\Omega$:
$$\mathcal F=\{\Omega\}\cup\left\{A\in\mathcal P(\Omega): \exists X\in\mathcal P(\mathcal G)\left(X\neq\varnothing\land A=\bigcap X\right)\right\}$$

Comment: In a certain sense, I can define an operation of infinite arity from $\mathcal{F}$ to the powerset of $\Omega$, namely $\bigcap$, in order to get the "trivial" recursion.